# How to get appointment body text for an appointment from outlook exchange server(EWS),c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to fetch email body from exchange server for an appointment for a particular room but did not get a success. Verified all the blogs over internet but nothing was of any help. Here is the code where  i am trying to contact exchange server to get the details:

## Approach A

```
service.GetUserAvailability
(
    attendees,
    new TimeWindow(twStart, twEnd),
    AvailabilityData.FreeBusy
).AttendeesAvailability[0].CalendarEvents;
```

## Approach B

```
public class MailItem
{
    public string From;
    public string[] Recipients;
    public string Subject;
    public string Body;
}

public static MailItem[] GetUnreadMailFromInbox(ExchangeService service, string address)
{
    // Address is the email address for an meeting room
    try
    {
        service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, address);
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(128));
        ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> items =
        service.BindToItems(findResults.Select(item => item.Id), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients));

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults2 = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(128));
        ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> items2 =
        service.BindToItems(findResults2.Select(item2 => item2.Id), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients));

        return items.Select(item =>
        {
            return new MailItem()
            {
                From = address,
                Recipients = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddressCollection)item.Item[EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients]).Select(recipient => recipient.Address).ToArray(),
                Subject = item.Item.Subject,
                Body = item.Item.Body.ToString(),
            };
        }).ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I need a solution for fetching the body content for appointments from exchange server.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are already connecting to the Exchange service successfully and only trying to retrieve appointments body part please try this.

Try Adding `EmailMessageSchema.Body` to your property set.

```
 service.BindToItems(findResults2.Select(item2 => item2.Id), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients));
```

Comment: Kinda nasty hack, but it sure works. In fact, it's the only thing I found working, since other hacks have failed. Also works with EmailMessageSchema.TextBody.